# Iterate through a JSON with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, amcharts

I am currently learning code while working at the same time here so I am new to this all. I am attempting to make charts using AMcharts. I need to make different data sets based on orientation and possibly more in the future. Below I show my current JSON and my code. The problem I'm having is I am getting data, but only the last 2 Test Results. I'm wondering what I need to adjust to get every set of data. Thank you for any help.

**JSON:**

```
"{"TestSets":{"#text":["\n  ","\n  ","\n"],"TestSet":[{"#text":["\n    ","\n    ","\n    ","\n    ","\n    ","\n    ","\n    ","\n    ","\n    ","\n  "],"TestSetID":{"#text":"TestSet_iOS1"},"Hardware":{"#text":"iPad Air 2"},"Version":{"#text":"iOS 8.1.3"},"Build":{"#text":"2.7.0.920"},"Orientation":{"#text":"PORTRAIT"},"NumTestCases":{"#text":"76"},"NumTestScripts":{"#text":"17"},"TotalTime":{"#text":"33823.411"},"TestResults":{"#text":["\n      ","\n      ","\n      ","\n    "],"TestRun":[{"#text":["\n        ","\n        ","\n        ","\n        ","\n        ","\n        ","\n        ","\n      "],"Date":{"#text":"24 Mar 2015"},"Hardware":{"#text":"iPad Air 2"},"Version":{"#text":"iOS 8.1.3"},"Build":{"#text":"2.7.0.907"},"Orientation":{"#text":"PORTRAIT"},"NumPassed":{"#text":"37"},"NumFailed":{"#text":"31"}},{"#text":["\n        ","\n        ","\n        ","\n        ","\n        ","\n        ","\n        ","\n      "],"Date":{"#text":"27 Mar 2015"},"Hardware":{"#text":"iPad Air 2"},"Version":{"#text":"iOS 8.1.3"},"Build":{"#text":"Pro 2.7.0.915"},"Orientation":{"#text":"PORTRAIT"},"NumPassed":{"#text":"100"},"NumFailed":{"#text":"25"}},{"#text":["\n        ","\n        ","\n        ","\n        ","\n        ","\n        ","\n        ","\n      "],"Date":{"#text":"29 Mar 2015"},"Hardware":{"#text":"iPad Air 2"},"Version":{"#text":"iOS 8.1.3"},"Build":{"#text":"2.7.0.920"},"Orientation":{"#text":"PORTRAIT"},"NumPassed":{"#text":"66"},"NumFailed":{"#text":"10"}}]}},{"#text":["\n    ","\n    ","\n    ","\n    ","\n    ","\n    ","\n    ","\n    ","\n    ","\n  "],"TestSetID":{"#text":"TestSet_iOS2"},"Hardware":{"#text":"iPad Air 2"},"Version":{"#text":"iOS 8.1.3"},"Build":{"#text":"Pro 2.7.0.920"},"Orientation":{"#text":"LANDSCAPE"},"NumTestCases":{"#text":"29"},"NumTestScripts":{"#text":"7"},"TotalTime":{"#text":"13666.919"},"TestResults":{"#text":["\n      ","\n      ","\n    "],"TestRun":[{"#text":["\n        ","\n        ","\n        ","\n        ","\n        ","\n        ","\n        ","\n      "],"Date":{"#text":"30 Mar 2015"},"Hardware":{"#text":"iPad Air 2"},"Version":{"#text":"iOS 8.1.3"},"Build":{"#text":"2.7.0.915"},"Orientation":{"#text":"LANDSCAPE"},"NumPassed":{"#text":"34"},"NumFailed":{"#text":"15"}},{"#text":["\n        ","\n        ","\n        ","\n        ","\n        ","\n        ","\n        ","\n      "],"Date":{"#text":"31 Mar 2015"},"Hardware":{"#text":"iPad Air 2"},"Version":{"#text":"iOS 8.1.3"},"Build":{"#text":"Pro 2.7.0.920"},"Orientation":{"#text":"LANDSCAPE"},"NumPassed":{"#text":"10"},"NumFailed":{"#text":"19"}}]}}]}}"
```

**Code:**

```
var chartData = [];
for (var i = 0; i < testJson["TestSets"]["TestSet"].length; i++) {
    var testResults = [];
    var runs = testJson["TestSets"]["TestSet"][i]["TestResults"]["TestRun"];
    for (var j = 0; j < runs.length; j++) {
        var run = runs[j];
        testResults.push({"date": run["Date"]["#text"], "NumPassed": run["NumPassed"]["#text"], "NumFailed": run["NumFailed"]["#text"], "Orientation": run["Orientation"]["#text"]});
    }
}
chartData.push(testResults);
console.log(chartData);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var chartData = [];
for (var i = 0; i < testJson["TestSets"]["TestSet"].length; i++) {
var testResults = [];
var runs = testJson["TestSets"]["TestSet"][i]["TestResults"]["TestRun"];
for (var j = 0; j < runs.length; j++) {
var run = runs[j];
testResults.push({"date": run["Date"]["#text"], "NumPassed": run["NumPassed"]["#text"], "NumFailed": run["NumFailed"]["#text"], "Orientation": run["Orientation"]["#text"]});
}
}
chartData.push(testResults);
console.log(chartData);
```

should be:

```
var chartData = [];
var testResults = [];
for (var i = 0; i < testJson["TestSets"]["TestSet"].length; i++) {
  var runs = testJson["TestSets"]["TestSet"][i]["TestResults"]["TestRun"];
  for (var j = 0; j < runs.length; j++) {
    var run = runs[j];
    testResults.push({"date": run["Date"]["#text"], "NumPassed": run["NumPassed"]["#text"], "NumFailed": run["NumFailed"]["#text"], "Orientation": run["Orientation"]["#text"]});
  }
}
chartData.push(testResults);
console.log(chartData);
```

Comment: You were filling testResults array, but then overwriting it on the second time through the `i` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is cleaned up and formatted as well.

```
/* global console */
/* global testJson */
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var chartData = [],
        testResults = [],
        runs, run;

    for (var i = 0; i < testJson.TestSets.TestSet.length; i++) {
        runs = testJson.TestSets.TestSet[i].TestResults.TestRun;
        for (var j = 0; j < runs.length; j++) {
            run = runs[j];
            testResults.push({
                'date': run.Date['#text'],
                'NumPassed': run.NumPassed['#text'],
                'NumFailed': run.NumFailed['#text'],
                'Orientation': run.Orientation['#text']
            });
        }
    }
    chartData.push(testResults);
    console.log(chartData);
}());
```

Some best practices suggest moving variable declaration to the top of the function, since this is what the interpreter is doing for you behind the scenes.  (javascript variables are function scoped, not block).